# Implementing efficient initialization of C++ Template List classes

Tags: c++, templates

For writing a template list class, the equivalent of vector (purely as a design exercise) I am trying to find out what is done to be efficient.

If one writes:

```
v = new T[size];
```

then the compiler will call the constructor for `T`, right?  `T()`.

So instead in the class below:

```
v = (T*) new char[sizeof(T) * size]
```

This seems easy enough.  However, in the destructor, how to delete just the ones that have been initialized?  In the following class, only the first "used" elements are initialized.

Also, in the copy constructor, how to call the copy constructor for `T` for only the used elements efficiently?

If I initialized the expensive way, it works:

```
v = new T[size];
for (int i = 0; i < used; i++)
  v[i] = orig.v[i];
```

but that requires that `v` already be intiialized with `T()`.  What is the better way?

Class is below:

```
#include <cstdint>

template<typename T>
class List {
private:
    uint32_t used;
    uint32_t capacity;
    T* v;
public:
    List(uint32_t cap) : used(0), capacity(cap), v((T*)new char[sizeof(T)*capacity]) {}
    ~List() {
        delete [] v; // no
    }
    List(const List& orig) : used(orig.used), capacity(orig.capacity), v((T*) new char[sizeof(T)*capacity]) {
        // now copy only the used ones
        for (int i = 0; i < used; i++)
            v[i] = orig.v[i]; // no, operator = will call destructor on v[i], but it is uninitialized
    }
};
```

Comment: Are you strongly attracted to array? You could use a `vector` + `reserve` and `emplace`... and of course provide appropriate constructor for initialization.

Comment: Using vector just pushes off the question.  This class is attempting to BE class vector, so I want to know how to make it work.

Comment: Sorry, I have missed the point. Gotta go to sleep, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be like `std::vector`, you need to use "placement new" and explicitly call destructors.

```
#include <new>

~List() {
    while (used) {
        --used;
        v[used]->~T();
    }
    delete[] reinterpret_cast<char*>(v);
}

List(const List& orig) : used(orig.used), capacity(orig.capacity),
    v(reinterpret_cast<T*>(new char[sizeof(T)*capacity])) {
    // now copy only the used ones
    for (int i = 0; i < used; i++)
        new(v+i) T(orig.v[i]);
}
```

Note the above copy constructor is not exception-safe.  Try to make it so.

Comment: Is there no way to manually copy individual elements?  Like calling the destructor?  I'm thinking of some kind of elided copy of each object from orig to my vector.

Comment: I don't know what you're asking.  `new(v+i) T(orig.v[i]);` does copy an individual element.

Comment: `::new((void*(v+i))`

Comment: @aschepter.  How does placement new allocate capacity elements, and initialize only used of them?  I would have the same problem there. I do not see how to trigger the constructor on used objects.

Comment: Placement new doesn't allocate memory, it directly calls a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

First, just use `std::vector<T>` instead of reimplementing this yourself.

What you're looking for here is *placement new* and *explicit destructor calls*.  Where normally, each `new` should be paired with a `delete`, each placement new should be paired with an explicit destructor call.

To answer your specific questions:

> However, in the destructor, how to delete just the ones that have been initialized?

Explicitly call their destructors, then `delete[]` the original `char[]` allocation correctly, which will (correctly) *not* automatically call any `T` destructors.

```
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < used; ++i) {
    v[i]->~T();
}

delete [] reinterpret_cast<char *>(v);
```

> Also, in the copy constructor, how to call the copy constructor for `T` for only the used elements efficiently?

You need to placement-new here.  Your line `v[i] = orig.v[i];` causes undefined behavior because `v[i]` has not yet been constructed.

Placement-new the objects instead (which you should do to each `v[i]` before you use it):

```
new(reinterpret_cast<char *>(v + i)) T(orig.v[i]);
```

Comment: `::new((void*)(v+i))`

Answer (score 0):

For in the copy constructor you can try this code:

`#include <cstring>`

```
List(const List& orig) : used(orig.used), capacity(orig.capacity), v((T*) new char[sizeof(T) * capacity]) {
        // now copy only the used ones
        memcpy(v, orig.v, sizeof(T)*capacity);
    }
```

or

```
List(const List& orig) : used(orig.used), capacity(orig.capacity), v((T*) new char[sizeof(T) * capacity]) {
        // now copy only the used ones
        memcpy_s(v, capacity, orig.v, sizeof(T)*capacity);
    }
```

Comment: No, if T contains pointers for example, this behavior is incorrect.

Comment: If `[T = int *]` for the above solution just create a new object and copy the address only. If we copy the value of each element to a new object, it becomes impossible. We do not know each element has what length, because we do not know every element initialization with new `int()` or `new int [capacity]`.
If `[T = List <int> *]` it's possible, but I need to fix the above solution.